# Prob. 21, Chap. 2, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: The union of two measurable sets is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Here is Prob. 21, Chap. 2, in the book *Real Analysis* by H.L. Royden and P.M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> Use property (ii) of Theorem 11 as the primitive definition of a measurable set and prove that the union of two measurable sets is measurable. Then do the same for property (iv).

Here is Theorem 11:

> Let $E$ be any set of real numbers. Then each of the following four assertions is equivalent to the measurability of $E$.

> (i) For each $\epsilon > 0$, there is an open set $O$ containing $E$ for which $m^*(O\setminus E) < \epsilon$.

> (ii) There is a $G_\delta$-set $G$ containing $E$ for which $m^*(G \setminus E) = 0$.

> (iii) For each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a closed set $F$ contained in $E$ for which $m^*(E \setminus F) < \epsilon$.

> (iv) There is an $F_\sigma$-set $F$ contained in $E$ for which $m^*(E \setminus F) = 0$.

My Attempt:

> Using property (ii) as the primitive definition of a measurable set, let us suppose that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are measurable sets, where $E_1 \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $E_2 \subset \mathbb{R}$ of course. Then there are $G_\delta$-sets $G_1$ and $G_2$ containing $E_1$ and $E_2$, respectively, for which
> $$
> m^* \left( G_1 \setminus E_1 \right) = 0 = m^* \left( G_2 \setminus E_2 \right). 
> $$

> As $E_1 \subset G_1$ and $E_2 \subset G_2$, so we also have $E_1 \cup E_2 \subset G_1 \cup G_2$.

> We show that $G_1 \cup G_2$ is also a $G_\delta$-set. As $G_1$ and $G_2$ are $G_\delta$-sets, so there are countable collections $\left\{ U_{1j} \right\}_{j=1}^\infty$ and $\left\{ U_{2k} \right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of open sets (of $\mathbb{R}$) such that
> $$
> G_1 = \bigcap_{j=1}^\infty U_{1j} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad G_2 = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty U_{2k}. 
> $$
> Then we obtain
> $$
> \begin{align}
> G_1 \cup G_2 &= \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^\infty U_{1j}  \right) \bigcup \left(  \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty U_{2k} \right) \\
> &= \bigcap_{j=1}^\infty  \left[ U_{1j} \bigcup  \left(  \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty U_{2k} \right) \right]  \\
> &= \bigcap_{j=1}^\infty  \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \left(  U_{1j} \bigcup U_{2k} \right),
> \end{align}
> $$
> whcih being the intersection of the  countable collection $\left\{ U_{1j} \cup U_{2k} \right\}_{j, k =1}^\infty$ of open sets is a $G_\delta$-set.

> Furthermore, we also find that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \left( G_1 \cup G_2 \right) \setminus \left( E_1 \cup E_2 \right) &= \left( G_1 \cup G_2 \right) \cap  \left( E_1 \cup E_2 \right)^C \\
> &= \left( G_1 \cup G_2 \right) \cap  \left( E_1^C \cap E_2^C \right) \\
> &= \left[ G_1 \cap \left( E_1^C \cap E_2^C \right) \right] \cup \left[ G_2 \cap \left( E_1^C \cap E_2^C \right) \right] \\
> &= \left[ \left(  G_1 \cap E_1^C \right)  \cap E_2^C \right] \cup \left[ G_2 \cap \left( E_2^C \cap E_1^C \right) \right] \\
> &= \left[ \left(  G_1 \cap E_1^C \right)  \cap E_2^C \right] \cup \left[ \left(  G_2 \cap E_2^C \right) \cap E_1^C \right] \\
> &\subset \left( G_1 \cap E_1^C \right) \cup \left( G_2 \cap E_2^C \right) \\
> &= \left( G_1 \setminus E_1 \right) \cup \left( G_2 \setminus E_2 \right).
> \end{align} 
> $$
> Thus we have the inclusion
> $$
> \left( G_1 \cup G_2 \right) \setminus \left( E_1 \cup E_2 \right) \ \subset \ \left( G_1 \setminus E_1 \right) \cup \left( G_2 \setminus E_2 \right).
> $$

Therefore using the monotonocity and sub-additivity of the outer measure, we have
$$
\begin{align}
0 &\leq m^* \left( \left( G_1 \cup G_2 \right) \setminus \left( E_1 \cup E_2 \right)  \right) \\ 
&\leq m^* \left( \left( G_1 \setminus E_1 \right) \cup \left( G_2 \setminus E_2 \right) \right) \\
&\leq m^* \left( G_1 \setminus E_1 \right) + m^* \left( G_2 \setminus E_2 \right) \\
&= 0 + 0 \\
&= 0,
\end{align}
$$
which implies that
$$
m^* \left( \left( G_1 \cup G_2 \right) \setminus \left( E_1 \cup E_2 \right)  \right) = 0.
$$

> Thus we have shown that there exists a $G_\delta$-set $G := G_1 \cup G_2$ for which
> $$
> m^* \left( G \setminus \left( E_1 \cup E_2 \right) \right) = 0. 
> $$
> Hence $E_1 \cup E_2$ is measurable.

Is this proof correct?

> Now using the property (iv), let us suppose that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are measurable sets. Then there are $F_\sigma$-sets $F_1$ and $F_2$ contained in $E_1$ and $E_2$, respectively, for which
> $$
> m^* \left( E_1 \setminus F_1 \right) = 0 = m^* \left( E_2 \setminus F_2 \right). 
> $$

> As $F_1 \subset E_1$ and $F_2 \subset E_2$, so $F_1 \cup F_2 \subset E_1 \cup E_2$.

> As $F_1$ and $F_2$ are $F_\sigma$-sets, so there are countable collections $\left\{ V_{1j} \right\}_{j=1}^\infty$ and $\left\{ V_{2k} \right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of closed sets of $\mathbb{R}$ for which
> $$
> F_1 = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty V_{1j} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad F_2 = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_{2k}. 
> $$
> Then we obtain
> $$
> F_1 \cup F_2 = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( V_{1j} \cup V_{2k} \right), 
> $$
> and thus $F_1 \cup F_2$, being the union of the countable collection $\left\{ V_{1j} \cup V_{2k} \right\}_{j, k = 1}^\infty$ of closed sets, is an $F_\sigma$-set.

> Furthermore, as before, since
> $$
> \left( E_1 \cup E_2 \right) \setminus \left( F_1 \cup F_2 \right)\ \subset \  \left( E_1 \setminus F_1 \right) \cup \left( E_2 \setminus F_2 \right), 
> $$
> therefore we have
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> 0 &\leq m^* \left( \left( E_1 \cup E_2 \right) \setminus \left( F_1 \cup F_2 \right)  \right) \\ 
> &\leq m^* \left( \left( E_1 \setminus F_1 \right) \cup \left( E_2 \setminus F_2 \right) \right) \\ 
> &\leq m^*  \left( E_1 \setminus F_1  \right) + m^* \left( E_2 \setminus F_2 \right) \\
> &= 0 + 0 \\
> &= 0,
> \end{align}
> $$
> and so
> $$
> m^* \left( \left( E_1 \cup E_2 \right) \setminus \left( F_1 \cup F_2 \right)  \right) = 0,
> $$

> Thus we have an $F_\sigma$ set $F := F_1 \cup F_2$ contined in $E_1 \cup E_2$ for which $m^* \left( \left( E_1 \cup E_2 \right) \setminus F \right) = 0$.
> Therefore it follows that set $E_1 \cup E_2$ is measurable.

Is this proof correct?

Are both of my above proofs correct and clear enough in each and every detail? Or, are there any issues?

Comment: Both of your proofs are fine.

Comment: Very good. It is useful to remember that the union of finitely many $G_{\delta}$ sets is  $G_{\delta}$, & similarly an intersection of finitely many $F_{\sigma}$ sets is  $F_{\sigma}$. In the last part of (ii) it is easier to say $(G_1\cup G_2)\setminus (E_1\cup E_2)=$ $[G_1\setminus (E_1\cup E_2)]\cup [G_2\setminus (E_1\cup E_2)]$ $\subset [G_1\setminus E_1]\cup [G_2\setminus E_2]$.

Comment: BTW from this we see that $E$ is measurable iff $G\supset E\supset F$ where $G$ is $G_{\delta}$ and $F$ is $F_{\sigma}$ and $m(G\setminus F)=0.$